# Periodically printing the number of open files for a process

Tags: macos, lsof

I can use a program like top to periodically update system statistics and I can use `lsof -p <pid> | wc -l` to give me a snapshot of the number open files for a process. Is there a command I can call that, like top, will periodically show me the number of open files for a process, updated every second or so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `watch`, if all you need is to call a command like `lsof -p <pid> | wc -l` periodically.

http://ss64.com/bash/watch.html

**Edit:**

Or just write a simple bash script that repeats a command periodically.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  lsof -p <pid> | wc -l
  sleep 2
done
```

Comment: Thanks. However, watch does not appear to be available on Mac OS X.

Comment: You can download and compile `watch` yourself, but I guess it's quicker to write a bash script :)